# Grayscaling doesn't affect my image

Tags: java, android, image-processing, bitmap, ocr

I am using tessaract to scan text and convert it into a string , so far so good , but i have a problem with grayscaling an image. I have images captured with my camera and I want to grayscale them and to rescale them in order to save some memory , i did this by using the BitmapFactory.Options and the method inSimpleSize(put it in 4).
After that i've tried to get the image from the folder that it  is and grayscale it. But didn't work - the text can't be extracted from the photo. However when i removed grayscaling worked. 
Here is my code :

```
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgUri.getPath() , options);
        //  bitmap = toGrayscale(bitmap);
        result = extractText(bitmap);

        textView.setText(result);
```

The extractText method simply calls Tessaract and scan the image and it's working fine without the grayscaling.

My toGrayscale code which i found online ( it is working , i have tried it as a filter and i was happy with it) :

```
public Bitmap toGrayscale(Bitmap bmpOriginal)
    {
        int width, height;
        height = bmpOriginal.getHeight();
        width = bmpOriginal.getWidth();

        Bitmap bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(bmpGrayscale);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
        cm.setSaturation(0);
        ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
        paint.setColorFilter(f);
        c.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, paint);
        return bmpGrayscale;
    }
```

Here is my code for capturing photos with the camera :

```
    if (captureImg != null) {
        captureImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startCameraActivity();
            }
     });
 private void startCameraActivity() {
    try {
        String IMGS_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Noetic/imgs";
        prepareDirectory(IMGS_PATH);

        String img_path = IMGS_PATH + "/ocr.jpg";

        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(img_path));

        final Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I was looking for a solution but didn't find anything. I have some theories why this doesn't work - one of them is because my grayscaling method creates the same image but new (so  BitmapFactory.Options.getSampleSize becomes useless). Any help will be much appriciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  `Bitmap bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);` instead of `Bitmap bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);`